# How to get real value from the ParameterInfo[] in Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

Actually I have few question to be easier to understand what I'm asking about I have to show my code first.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();
    customClass.SomeMethod("asdas", true, 30.5);

}

public class CustomClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public Boolean SomeMethod(String a, Boolean b, Double c)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute()
    {
        SomeIntercepter.InterceptEverything();
    }
    public void DoSomethingBeforeMethodexecutes()
    {
      ....
    }
    public void DoSomethingAfterMethodExecutes()
    {
      ....
    }
}

public class SomeIntercepter
{
    public static void InterceptEverything()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var method = stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod();
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length > 3)
            return;

        String cacheKey = method.Name;

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            //HOW TO GET THE PARAMETER DATA ASSIGNED
            cacheKey += "_" + parameters[i];
        }
    }
}
```

So what I try to do. I try to intercept method on each it call and do something based on the incomming data of the method which is marked with `[MyAttribute]`. So I access the method through the StackTrace and try to get all incomming data with GetParameters.
And here is my questions:
     1) How to object[] of all incomming data of the `SomeMethod` in the InterceptEverything()
     2) How to say to the `MyAttribute` to run before marked method with `MyAttribute` to run method `DoSomethingBeforeMethodexecutes()`
     3) How to say to the  `MyAttribute` to run after marked method with `MyAttribute` to run method `DoSomethingAfterMethodexecutes()`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the *values* from any particular frame via `ParameterInfo`. This facility does not exist.

Also: attributes do not *execute*. Unless you are using something like postsharp, they are just *information*. To get them to *execute* you must explicitly write reflection code to do that.

Comment: But how can I get it from StackTrace?

Comment: @Maris there's a question you jumped: *can* I get it from StackTrace. To which the answer is: no, you cannot.

Comment: @Maris: You cannot. You need a debugger or profiler to get that info.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Or derive from a security attribute and pass `Demand` to the constructor (comment intentionally vague)

Comment: @leppie yeah, I was deliberately avoiding mentioning security attributes, because a: that's evil, b: they don't run in full trust, c: that's evil

Comment: Ok maybe not stack trace. Can I get somehow in InterceptEverything() the entire data of method which calls it?

Comment: @Maris no, you cannot, unless you are a debugger

Comment: @MarcGravell: Pretty sure they run in full trust. Got bitten by it recently.

Comment: I have a lot of classes, each class have few methods I want to say all methods of those classes to run in something like container. which will do something before the method runs(what it will do is based on the incomming data of the method), and do something after it return the value and do something(based on what data was returned). Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: @leppie my memory of that is different, but frankly it is a faff to set up a test project and I'm lazy

Comment: @Maris you might want to look at what things like postsharp bring to that, or maybe any of the decorator-based frameworks. There is nothing inbuilt that will do that for you.

Comment: Can you show some code-example of postsharp that will help me to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737833/how-do-i-add-arguments-to-postsharp-attributes

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like it will help, Thanks a lot!